# How to add value to array with JMESPath?

Tags: jmespath

With the following JSON:

```json
{
   "resource_access":{
      "info-bi-test":{
         "roles":[
            "DB7"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

How to add another value to an array `resource_access."info-bi-test".roles` with JMESPath?

I read the documentation of JMESPath and found the `merge` function, but it only works with objects.

Comment: How do you want to declare which list should be an item added to? Imagine, there might `{"roles1":["DB7"], "roles2":["XP7"]}`.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea to add item(s) to an existing array is to create an array of array(s) and then [flatten](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#flatten-operator) it.

As an example, a totally static query like

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']][]
```

Will give:

```json
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c",
  "d",
  "e"
]
```

---

Now, since you are not giving a desired output, there are multiple cases:

1. You want to add one hardcoded item to the array `resource_access."info-bi-test".roles`, and have a simple array as return, with a desired output like

   ```json
   ["DB7", "DB9"]
   ```

   Then, this could be achieved with the query:

   ```
   [resource_access."info-bi-test".roles, 'DB9'][]
   ```
2. You want to add multiple items to the array `resource_access."info-bi-test".roles`, and have a simple array as return, with a desired output like

   ```json
   ["DB7", "DB9", "DB11"]
   ```

   Then, this could be achieved with the query:

   ```
   [resource_access."info-bi-test".roles, ['DB9', 'DB11']][]
   ```
3. You want to add one item to the array `resource_access."info-bi-test".roles` form somewhere else in the JSON structure, with an input like

   ```json
   {
     "resource_access":{
       "info-bi-test":{
         "roles":[
           "DB7"
         ]
       }
     },
     "default_role": "DB9"
   }
   ```

   and have a simple array as return, with a desired output like

   ```json
   ["DB7", "DB9"]
   ```

   Then, this could be achieved with the query:

   ```
   [resource_access."info-bi-test".roles, default_role][]
   ```
4. You want to add multiple items to the array `resource_access."info-bi-test".roles` form somewhere else in the JSON structure, with an input like

   ```json
   {
     "resource_access": {
       "info-bi-test": {
         "roles":[
           "DB7"
         ]
       }
     },
     "default_roles": [
       "DB9",
       "DB11"
     ]
   }
   ```

   and have a simple array as return, with a desired output like

   ```json
   ["DB7", "DB9", "DB11"]
   ```

   Then, this could be achieved with the query:

   ```
   [resource_access."info-bi-test".roles, default_roles][]
   ```
5. You want to add one hardcoded item to the array `resource_access."info-bi-test".roles`, but you want the whole object structure returned, with a desired output like

   ```json
   {
     "resource_access": {
       "info-bi-test": {
         "roles": [
           "DB7",
           "DB9"
         ]
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Then, you will have to recreate the object structure in the query:

   ```
   {
     resource_access: {
       "info-bi-test": {
         roles: [resource_access."info-bi-test".roles, 'DB9'][]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
6. You want to add multiple hardcoded items to the array `resource_access."info-bi-test".roles`, but you want the whole object structure returned, with a desired output like

   ```json
   {
     "resource_access":{
       "info-bi-test":{
         "roles":[
           "DB7",
           "DB9",
           "DB11"
         ]
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Then, you will have to recreate the object structure in the query:

   ```
   {
     resource_access: {
       "info-bi-test": {
         roles: [resource_access."info-bi-test".roles, ['DB9', 'DB11']][]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
7. You want to add one item to the array `resource_access."info-bi-test".roles` form somewhere else in the JSON structure, with an input like

   ```json
   {
     "resource_access":{
       "info-bi-test":{
         "roles":[
           "DB7"
         ]
       }
     },
     "default_role": "DB9"
   }
   ```

   but you want the whole object structure returned, with a desired output like

   ```json
   {
     "resource_access":{
       "info-bi-test":{
         "roles":[
           "DB7",
           "DB9"
         ]
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Then, you will have to recreate the object structure in the query:

   ```
   {
     resource_access: {
       "info-bi-test": {
         roles: [resource_access."info-bi-test".roles, default_role][]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
8. You want to add multiple items to the array `resource_access."info-bi-test".roles` form somewhere else in the JSON structure, with an input like

   ```json
   {
     "resource_access":{
       "info-bi-test":{
         "roles":[
           "DB7"
         ]
       }
     },
     "default_roles": [
       "DB9",
       "DB11"
     ]
   }
   ```

   but you want the whole object structure returned, with a desired output like

   ```json
   {
     "resource_access":{
       "info-bi-test":{
         "roles":[
           "DB7",
           "DB9",
           "DB11"
         ]
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   Then, you will have to recreate the object structure in the query:

   ```
   {
     resource_access: {
       "info-bi-test": {
         roles: [resource_access."info-bi-test".roles, default_roles][]
       }
     }
   }
   ```

So, as you can see, they are all flavour of the same principle: nest everything in an array and flatten it.